# Unable to restore database backup on Postgresql-10.0

Tags: linux, postgresql, pg-restore

I am using postgresql-9.4 (port 5432) and postgresql-10.0 (port 5433) on my Linux machine (RHEL 7.4). Postgresql-9.4 was installed using yum repository and Postgresql-10.0 was installed using source in different partitions.

I have taken a backup of db (dtbase.backup) on Postgresql-9.4 using it's pg_dump and trying to restore this on Postgresql-10.0 using it's pg_restore.

While doing this, I am getting below error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header
```

I have checked different forums but unable to find the solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: /home/post10/bin/pg_restore is the default path of pg_restore for Postgresql-10

Comment: /home/post10/bin/pg_restore -l /tmp/dtbase.backup | head -n 20 giving me the same error.

Comment: try taking dum with oder pg_dump?..

Comment: older pg_dump is working fine. Dumping the database as dtbase.backup with pg_dump of 9.4

Comment: so `/home/post10/bin/pg_dump` creates a backup too advanced for `/home/post10/bin/pg_restore`?.. hm... no ideas

Comment: I have taken the backup of dtbase using pg_dump of 9.4 to restore it in 10.0. I have not checked pg_dump of 10 as it has no database to take backup of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to upgrade your PostgreSQL v10 to 10.3 so that you have commit [b8a2908f0ac735da68d49be2bce2d523e363f67b](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=b8a2908f0ac735da68d49be2bce2d523e363f67b):

```
Avoid using unsafe search_path settings during dump and restore.

Historically, pg_dump has "set search_path = foo, pg_catalog" when
dumping an object in schema "foo", and has also caused that setting
to be used while restoring the object.  This is problematic because
functions and operators in schema "foo" could capture references meant
to refer to pg_catalog entries, both in the queries issued by pg_dump
and those issued during the subsequent restore run.  That could
result in dump/restore misbehavior, or in privilege escalation if a
nefarious user installs trojan-horse functions or operators.

This patch changes pg_dump so that it does not change the search_path
dynamically.  The emitted restore script sets the search_path to what
was used at dump time, and then leaves it alone thereafter.  Created
objects are placed in the correct schema, regardless of the active
search_path, by dint of schema-qualifying their names in the CREATE
commands, as well as in subsequent ALTER and ALTER-like commands.

Since this change requires a change in the behavior of pg_restore
when processing an archive file made according to this new convention,
bump the archive file version number; old versions of pg_restore will
therefore refuse to process files made with new versions of pg_dump.

Security: CVE-2018-1058
```

Your 9.4 installation already uses archive format 1.13, which your v10 installation does not yet understand.

Besides, you should *always* use `pg_dump` from the higher PostgreSQL version to upgrade a database.

Comment: So, how can I upgrade this if I have installed it using source? Do I need to uninstall it first? I am newbie.

Comment: You can uninstall 10.0 and replace it, or you can install 10.3 in a different location (`configure --prefix`).

Comment: I have solved it without upgrading. I took backup again using pg_dump of 10.0 instead of 9.4 and pg_restore worked this time

Comment: Of course. Still you should upgrade, as 10.0 is buggy and insecure.